# iOS in-app purchases randomly not being recognized, or never recognized to begin with

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Ok this one really has me stumped and if anyone can figure it out I will love you long time. I have several iOS apps and I'm getting a lot of reports from users that when they pay using apple's in-app payment system to purchase app upgrades, the apps are not recognizing their purchase, or sometimes it recognizes it for a day and then it stops working.

The weird thing is I have tested it on my iPhone and iPad, both in sandbox and after publishing with a real account, and I never have these issues. I thought maybe it was an issue with the new iOS 11 but even users on iOS 10 and 9 are reporting this issue. For some users, uninstalling the apps and downloading again from app store, then clicking restore purchases button fixes it, but for most user's it doesn't.

I have tried everything apple recommends, such as telling users to make sure they are using the correct apple ID, making sure the device is set to allows in-app payments, etc but none of those solutions apply or work.

So without further ado, here's my code

SharedDefaults

```
fileprivate enum SUDK: String {
case updatedToProVersion = "UDK_UPDATED_TO_PRO_VERSION"
}

public class SharedDefaults: NSObject {
public static var shared: SharedDefaults!

private let defaults: UserDefaults

public init(groupIdentifier: String) {
    if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: groupIdentifier) {
        defaults = userDefaults
    } else {
        defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        assert(false, "Defaults could not be created with the given app         group - \(groupIdentifier)")
    }

    super.init()
}

public static var isPremiumVersionActive: Bool {
    set {
        shared.defaults.set(newValue, forKey:  SUDK.updatedToProVersion.rawValue)
    }
    get {
        //// return true to set pro version to always on. This is the in-app purchase the user can make to upgrade the app.
        ////return true
        return shared.defaults.bool(forKey: SUDK.updatedToProVersion.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Upgrade Screen and Purchase Handlers

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class UpgradeNowController: UITableViewController {
//MARK: Constants
struct CellIdentifiers {
    static let buttonCell = "UpgradeNowButtonCell"
    static let discountedButtonCell = "UpgradeNowDiscountedButtonCell"
    static let buttonOnlyCell = "UpgradeNowButtonOnlyCell"
    static let detailCell = "UpgradeNowDetailCell"
}


//MARK: Variables
var allProducts = [SKProduct]()
var products = [SKProduct]()
public var activeProductID: String!
var detailItems: [(title: String, detail: String, image: String?)] = []

//MARK: Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    activeProductID = RageProducts.proversionupgrade

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reload), for: .valueChanged)

    let restoreButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Restore",
                                        style: .plain,
                                        target: self,
                                        action: #selector(UpgradeNowController.restoreTapped(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = restoreButton

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UpgradeNowController.handlePurchaseNotification(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification),
                                           object: nil)

    configureTableView()
    reloadTableView()
    configureDetailItems()
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: nil)
}


func reload() {
    products = []

    tableView.reloadData()

    RageProducts.store.requestProducts{ [weak self] success, products in
        if success {
            self?.allProducts = products!
            self?.products = products!.filter { $0.productIdentifier == self?.activeProductID }
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        self?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}

func restoreTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    RageProducts.store.restorePurchases()
}

func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let productID = notification.object as? String else { return }

    for (index, product) in products.enumerated() {
        guard product.productIdentifier == productID else { continue }

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
    }

    SharedDefaults.isPremiumVersionActive = true
}




//MARK: IAPPopupViewControllerDelegate
extension UpgradeNowController: IAPPopupViewControllerDelegate {

func iapPopupViewController(_ viewController: IAPPopupViewController,  didTapCancelForProduct product: SKProduct) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
}

func iapPopupViewController(_ viewController: IAPPopupViewController, didTapPurchaseForProduct product: SKProduct) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
    RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
}

}
```

IAPHelper

```
import StoreKit

public typealias ProductIdentifier = String
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()

open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

  static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"
    fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
  fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()
  fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
  fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

  public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
productIdentifiers = productIds
for productIdentifier in productIds {
  let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
  if purchased {
    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
    print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
  } else {
    print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
  }
}
super.init()
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
 }

}

// MARK: - StoreKit API

extension IAPHelper {

  public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
productsRequest?.cancel()
productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
productsRequest!.delegate = self
productsRequest!.start()
  }

  public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
  }

  public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
 }

 public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
   return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
 }

  public func restorePurchases() {
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
 }
}

// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
let products = response.products
print("Loaded list of products...")
productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
clearRequestAndHandler()

for p in products {
  print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle)    \(p.price.floatValue)")
}
}

public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error)         {
print("Failed to load list of products.")
print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
clearRequestAndHandler()
}

 private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
productsRequest = nil
productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
}
}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

 public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
  for transaction in transactions {
  switch (transaction.transactionState) {
  case .purchased:
    complete(transaction: transaction)
    break
  case .failed:
    fail(transaction: transaction)
    break
  case .restored:
    restore(transaction: transaction)
    break
  case .deferred:
    break
  case .purchasing:
    break
  }
 }
 }

private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
print("complete...")
deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
 }

private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
 }

 private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
print("fail...")
if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError? {
  if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
    print("Transaction Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error?.localizedDescription))")
  }
}

SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
 }

private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
 }
}
```

Note: lots of code has been stripped I've only included relevant code to the in app purchases. Maybe someone can look at it and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong but as far as I can see and research I've followed all guidelines for storekit and in app purchases as best as possible.

Comment: The main thing that I can see that you persist the purchase in the standard user defaults but in other code you are checking an app group user defaults. Is it possible that this is causing your issue?

Comment: Well, I have a today widget that check the app group defaults for if the upgrade is purchased, because the today widget is in an app group.

However, there are like 5 or 6 other features in the app that get enabled with the in-app purchase upgrade and none of those are working either.

Comment: @ user4106398 Did you ever resolve this problem?